# Audio is vague when earphones plugged in

Tags: audio, headphones

On my PC (Windows 10), when my earphones are plugged in, the sounds are kind of fuzzy. It's hard to explain the phenomenon in words, so I'll describe a little experiment that illustrates the issue.

When configuring the speaker balance as in the following picture (the default setting) and playing a song, I can hear the melody, but I can barely hear the singing. I cannot understand the words being sang, they sound like humming. Also, the music lacks clarity and is sort of distorted.

[image: balanced]

When configuring the balance all the way towards right (as in the picture below), I can hear the singing clearly, but not the background music.

[image: right]

And in the following configuration, I don't hear the singing at all, not even humming, but the background music is clear.

[image: left]

The results of the left and right tests are not surprising, because that's how stereo works. But the fact that the sound is fuzzy when the balance is set to default is clearly a problem.

The same problem happens with every pair of earphones I have tried. These earphones work perfectly on other computers. The phenomenon is evident not only when playing songs but also when playing any kind of sound (such as audio books, lectures, movies, etc.).

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is present even when using external speakers. When plugging in external speakers and playing songs, the words of the songs can be heard, but the quality is not very good.

Comment: Something, somewhere is out of phase. Either your audio settings are set to 5.1 not Stereo, or the connections on your headset do not match the expectations of the machine's socket. The latter is most likely if the headset is a 'phone' type with 4 silver bands on the plug [ie 2 speakers & a microphone], rather than a 'computer' type, with only 3 bands [just speakers]. (or vice versa)